# How can a boolean be appended to a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My approach is:

```
def build_layers():
    layers = ()
    for i in range (0, 32):
        layers += (True)
```

but this leads to

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "bool") to tuple
```

Context: This should prepare a call of [bpy.ops.pose.armature_layers](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_9/bpy.ops.pose.html) therefore I can't choose a list.

Comment: You should probably use a list here, as `layers += (True,)` will create a new tuple each time: `layers = []; layers.append(True)`

Comment: Indeed, tuples are immutable by nature. What you are doing here is creating a new tuple object each time

Comment: did you try at least that you can't choose a list ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(True)` is not a tuple.

Do this instead:

```
layers += (True, )
```

Even better, use a generator:

```
(True, ) * 32
```

Comment: it should be tuple(x for x in range(0, 32))

Comment: How about `(True,)*32`?

Comment: Thanks, of course I need some logic to decide which boolean value to append, therefore * 32 wouldn't work.

Comment: @stacker your code does not show anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

Since tuples are immutable, each concatenation creates a new tuple. It is better to do something like:

```
def build_layers(count):
    return tuple([True]*count)
```

If you need some logic to the tuple constructed, just use a list comprehension or generator expression in the tuple constructor:

```
>>> tuple(bool(ord(e)%2) for e in 'abcdefg')
(True, False, True, False, True, False, True)
```

Answer (score 1):

only a tuple can be add to tuple so this would be a working code

```
def build_layers():
    layers = ()
    for i in range (0, 32):
        layers += (True,)
```

However adding tuple is not very pythonic

```
def build_layers():
    layers = []
    for i in range (0, 32):
        layers.append(True)
    return tuple(layers)
```

if the True value depend on i you can make a function

```
def f(i):
    True

def build_layers():
    layers = []
    for i in range (0, 32):
        layers.append(f(i))
    return tuple(layers)
```

but this is typically best suited in a generator expression

```
def build_layers():
    return tuple(f(i) for i in range(0,32))
```

by the way the start value of a range is default 0

so this equally work

```
def build_layers():
    return tuple(f(i) for i in range(32))
```